# Lotus Notes: error when compose a form

Tags: runtime-error, lotus-notes

There is an old application, in which when we try to compose a (new) form in the bottom bar of Lotus client it appears:

`"Error logging error in line: N)"` - where N is a positive number.

I assume is refers to a written library, but is there any way I can see the exact "place" where the problem appears? I tried with Debug LotusScript but I can not see where the problem is.

I'll appreciate any tips or help. Thanks for your time.

- The code from the action button is:

`@Command([Compose];"MainFm");
@Command([ViewRefreshFields])`

Comment: What is the actual server version and what is the last known version where this app works fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error line comes probably from a `print()` line in LotusScript. Search in LotusScript libraries for "Error logging error". If you found it figure there out what's the reason for error.

You can search in Designer in menu "Search / File"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are quite a lot libraries written in LotusScript. Is there any chance I can find out the exact "problem" library?

Comment: Added a picture to show how to search in all design elements for a string.

Comment: I found it. It is an Const variable. But if I know that N ( the number of line ) where the problem exists, could I find the exact place of the problem?

Comment: Now look where the Const variable is used.

Comment: Switch on "Show line numbers" in Designer Preferences "General / Editors / Text Editors". Then you see a line number in front of every code line.